# Recursively index arbitrarily nested slice/array

Tags: go

I'm looking for the go equivalent of something like the below python snippet

```
indexes = [0,4]
nestedArray = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8]] # could be [][][]string, [][][][]float.. etc
def getNestedIndex(nestedArray, indexes):
  curr = nestedArray
  while indexes {
    curr = nestedArray[indexes.pop(0)]
  }
return curr # should be 5
```

I tried something like this

```
func nestedArrayIndex(slice []interface{}, indexes []int) interface{} {
    if len(indexes) == 1 {
        return slice[indexes[0]]
    }
    var newSlice []interface{}
    newSlice = slice[indexes[0]]
    return nestedArrayIndex(newSlice, indexes[1:])
}
```

but two things occur here - `[]Type != []interface{}` and `[][]..Type` definitely won't work here.

Wondering if there's a way to achieve this in go?

Comment: This is not exactly idiomatic Go code. What is the use case for this?

Comment: There are 3rd party libs that support this, e.g. [`github.com/icza/dyno`](https://github.com/icza/dyno) (disclosure: I'm the author) which supports indexing maps and slices, embedded in any depth.

Comment: for each level you have to cast the exact type

Comment: Yeah, I am realizing that this is not the way to approach my problem, was just wondering if there was something possible - going down a more iterative (and I believe more go-like)  approach. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `reflect`. `reflect.Value` has a method `Index` for getting the item of the index in the slice underlying the `Value`.

```
func nestedArrayIndex(slice interface{}, indexes []int) interface{} {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    for _, i := range indexes {
        v = v.Index(i)
    }
    return v.Interface()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Tmdomx18qPg